# SQL Update column value of row 1 from value of row 2

Tags: sql

Hi all
We are using SQL 2005 (MS),

I have a table that stores transactions. each time a specific event occurs 3 rows are added to for a specific transaction to that table.

Now we want to change (update) a column in row 1 called commision which in row 1 is null with the value of the same column  from row 2 which has a value say 123. is that possible?

Comment: just to clarify that the i want row 2 from the same table not different tables

Answer (score 1):

```
update mytable a
   set commission = ( select commission
                        from mytable b
                       where a.transaction = b.transaction
                         and b.event = 'row 2 event' ) // some value that selects row 2
  where a.event = 'row 1 event'                        // some value that selects row 1
    and a.transaction = 'specific transaction'         // leave off for all transactions
```

From your comment I've reformatted the statement to be:

```
UPDATE PAYMENT a
SET COMMISSION= ( SELECT COMMISSION
                    FROM PAYMENT b
                   WHERE b.PAYMENT_SEQ = 3
                     AND a.transaction_ID = b.TRANSACTION_ID )
WHERE a.PAYMENT_SEQ = 1
  AND a.TRANSACTION_ID = 1234
```

Why use IN(1234) when =1234 is simpler and gets the same result.  You can just match a.transaction_id = b.transaction_id in the inner select so you don't have to repeat your 1234 transaction selection on the inner select.

This syntax will work with other SQL versions but not SQL Server 2005 as LarsH has tested.  The a alias will have to be removed from the statement.

Comment: paul, from your example code the commision needs to be from the same table.. so what i am trying to do is  set the commision of event 1 to the commision of event 2 from the exact same table... not a different one as u specified (mytable b).

Comment: I have tried this query :UPDATE PAYMENT SET COMMISSION= ( SELECT COMMISSION FROM PAYMENT P WHERE P.PAYMENT_SEQ = 3 AND TRANSACTION_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TRANSACTION t WHERE ID IN (1234)) ) WHERE PAYMENT_SEQ = 1 AND TRANSACTION_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TRANSACTION t WHERE ID IN (1234))

Comment: Umm...mytable a and mytable b refer to the same table.

Comment: @Paul, when I try this in SQL Server (2008), it doesn't allow the "a" syntax after "update payment". I imagine that's why andreas had to use a different query. Were you thinking your solution worked in SQLServer?

Comment: Hmmm.  I've made an invalid assumption about the UPDATE syntax in SQL Server 2005.